# macro to count the number of entities in a field

Tags: parsing, excel, vba

I have to write a macro to show the number of entities in one column in another column.

Suppose one column in excel has the record a,b,c,d,e

I have to show the number of occurrences, i.e. eliminate the comma and  show the number 5.. this is the basic with logic, there are of course more variations

this has to be done in VB for macros in excel..

would appreciate any help.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need the split function - check the "counting words" example from [The Versatile Split Function](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/site/tip/the_versatile_split_function/)

Here it is, modified to use commas

```
Function WordCount(txt) As Long
'   Returns the number of words in a string
    Dim x As Variant
    txt = Application.Trim(txt)
    x = Split(txt, ",")
    WordCount = UBound(x) + 1
End Function
```